# Groovy : java introspection is bypassing metaprogramming. How to fix that?

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming, introspection

I'm trying to redefine a method of a class for test purpose.

For doing this I'm using the meta-programming feature of Groovy.

Unfortunately this method is called by introspection by some code out of my control.

In this situation the real method is called instead of the overridden version.

Here is a groovy script example demonstrating this:

```
class Dummy { void sayHello() {println "Hi"} }

def dummy = new Dummy()
dummy.sayHello()

dummy.metaClass.sayHello = {println "Hello world"}
dummy.sayHello()

def method = dummy.class.getDeclaredMethod("sayHello")
method.invoke(dummy)
```

This code output is:

> Hi
>   Hello world
>   Hi

But I would like the last line to be 'Hello World'

I have tried to override the Method.invoke method, but it was a mess.

Is there a preferred way to tell to Groovy that it should also intercept call to Method.invoke when a call to Dummy#sayHello is detected ?

Comment: Not that I know of, `getDeclaredMethod` is invoked from the Java side of things, and Java hs no concept of the metaClass

Comment: `dummy.invokeMethod("sayHello", dummy)` should do it, but I guess that is outside of your scope as you mentioned.

Comment: Maybe come at it from a different direction?  Which testing framework are you using? Not sure this will help though, as you don't have an example of what you're trying to do

Comment: I'm using Mockito, but unfortunately Mockito does not work well with Groovy. So for this particular Groovy service I was trying to mock using groovy feature. Now I found a way to 'patch' mockito/groovy with the mockito-groovy-support project, so I can use mockito as usual and this issue is not blocking me anymore. However I'm still curious on how one can be sure that metaclass change will be picked up by introspection.